# Would (potentially) hundreds of formats of a USB drive degrade its quality in any way?

Tags: usb, formatting, format

I have been considering the following setup for a home forensic workstation:

Machine A - my main machine, used for preparing files
Machine B - the isolated forensic workstation, disconnected from my network and used for collecting data
Machine C - a small raspberry pi who's only purpose is to automatically format any USB device connected to it
USB flash drive - to transfer files from A to B, then to be formatted by C

The use of this layout would be to gather files to be quarantined, put them on the USB flash drive, plug the USB drive into Machine B, then plug the USB drive into Machine C for a clean format. In doing this, my USB drive would be going through many passes of formatting. I started wondering if multiple clean formats of a USB flash drive, or any drive, would degrade in anyway it's ability to perform or expected life.

Considering this entire plan is entirely theoretical, I'm uninterested in any other logical/elegant solutions on completing the workstation, transferring files, ect.

Comment: are we talking USB HDD or USB flash drive?

Comment: Alternative to your forensic solution: Encrypt the files with a huge key, move the drive to B, decrypt (type the password in manually) and store. Normally delete the container on the USB drive, then make machine A forget the key (just don't save it anywhere, let RAM forget it. If paranoid, seek a method to wipe used RAM or just garble it with random things) and the files are effectively gone.

Comment: Flash memory devices have limited number of writes.  A mechanical storage device does not have any specific limit but depending on how full the disk was, would mean the drive would simply be under more overal strain then in a traditional usage.  Since every mechanical drive has a different history and even expected lifespan its hard to estimate.  A flash drive's lifespan is fixed although likely unknown to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the wikipedia article on flash memory;

> Another limitation is that flash memory has a finite number of program-erase cycles (typically written as P/E cycles). Most commercially available flash products are guaranteed to withstand around 100,000 P/E cycles before the wear begins to deteriorate the integrity of the storage.[21] Micron Technology and Sun Microsystems announced an SLC NAND flash memory chip rated for 1,000,000 P/E cycles on 17 December 2008.[22]

So I would surmise that you would notice an effect after a high number of writes back to the drive, however I've had USB flash memory devices which have been kicking around for years and they have been written and rewritten 1000s of times without any problems.

Comment: Cheap USB sticks will deteriorate WAY earlier. Sometimes as little as 500 writes.. It's horrible.

Answer (score 0):

If your USB drive is a solid state device (I mean, it is not a magnetic external hard disk), yes, you have a limit on how many write cycles you can use on it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive#Longevity

Answer (score 0):

Hundreds would be of no effect or negligible.

Flash based storage has a limited amount of writes before the tiny transistors start to fail. However "hundreds" should not be enough to cause issues.

Per [Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive)

> with steady improvements in size and price per capacity expected.[4]
>   Some allow up to 100,000 write/erase cycles, depending on the exact
>   type of memory chip used, and a 10-year shelf storage time.[5][6][7]